# Illustrator CC 2019 No canvas in new file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I recently Updated Illustrator to 2019 CC and now each time I create a new file, the Artboard is not shown or probably is transparent and instead there are a lot of rulers and guides. Although when I create new files using the adobe templates, it works fine and shows the artboards. I looked through the setting and preferences to see if anything new has been added and caused this but I didn't find anything useful. How can I bring the last version's canvas back? 
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's Video Canvas :D**

Actually you creating new document in video presets that's why camera frame is popping. use other preset like web or mobile or papers and create new document with that as shown in below image and you will be fine :) Hope it helps! and if you want to remove those photoshop like pixels simply use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+D</kbd> to hide/show transparency Grid :)

[image]